# Spam email text analysis

Tags: spam

A spam email was filtered by my email service provider.

The obvious footprints such as email address, 'click here' links, coupon code, urgency to receive the rewards are all there. At the bottom of the email, the text below was present. This text was hidden by a black text highlight colour. Note there is a blank space between the email body and the text below. Presumably, for a handheld smart device user who at a first glance will be unable to see the text below on its screen.

Question. What is a purpose of such a text? To fool the spam filters in an attempt to appear a genuine email (not to mention a deliberate spelling mistakes are included)? Surely the other attributes mentioned above will block the email anyway then why the additional text?

Here is the text.

*For starters, I've been patronizing M Grill for years. I think it hit its prime (with me) two years ago; since aphidsn externalisations staff seems to change frequently and with this, idem level of service has been quite volatile. I don't require a lot of attention at Fogo or M grill; I just need my bottle of water replaced once in a while, plates cleared when heroicsy've been placed to keratogenous side, some "is everything okays?" And I'll be a happy camper. I don't feel like I should go on a witch hunt to find some attention. My last visit I went for a quite little dinner. No one stopped by our table after we sat and got our initial bottle of pelligrino; I'm parched, annoyed bc I want some bread and a little service, and to top things off a busser drops a dirty fork off his tray and into my favorite LV bag, jokes, and laughs. Mind you, he didn't even collect our table's plates. I didn't think it was amusing. Very fortunate for fuselagesir manager, Robert Ilgenfritz, who made up for all clapperboards mishaps of blanketers evening. Our server can thank him for jovialise 22% tip he got. And M Grill can feel confident ensepulchersy have found a good find in hiring him. He was constantly walking around dialogs restaurant, which is why I even got any attention. And, why my bag will be receiving a nice dry cleaning.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, it is an attempt to fool the spam filter by throwing off the statistical analysis of the text.  Without all this nonsense text, the filter would rate it, say "90% likely to be spam" because of "Click Here" and other text.  Now, with all this business speak in the hidden text, the filter can't be so sure and might rate it "50% likely" and with a better rating might squeak under the block.  Also, the nonsense text would allow way more randomization so that it wouldn't match at all an otherwise identical email that has been flagged by a human as junk.

You said "Surely the other attributes will block..."  It really depends on how the filter is configured.  This wasn't a sophisticated attempt but administrators are always tweaking the configuration so that they don't lose important emails.  So, it is never a yes or no answer to "Is this Spam" but a likelyhood so that an admin can say, "We want to block what our filter says is 75% or more likely to be spam but allow everything else"  Then, it becomes an arms race of fooling the spam filter.